# In Smart phones navigation bar (Menu) or my new design not scrolling

Tags: html, css, mobile-development

Designed a new template for my website but navigation bar (Menu) in mobile not scrolling.

Site menu is working on Hover function. Site menu is working fine in laptop desktop but when we are checking in smartphone then after open mega menu its not scrolling to see all submenu. When we are trying to scroll menu then its scrolling page not menu.

Please suggest me if we are missing any code. Site is here http://rsseosolution.com/newsite/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not possible to tell you if there is anything wrong with your code if you do not provide any code. Please refer to the help page on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: in your site you are adding ``sticky`` class for mobile to ``id="navbar"`` and your ``sticky`` class contain     ``position: fixed;``  css

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.